# how to use Format String in Realm React Native

Tags: react-native, realm

in the https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/ mentioned that we can use of format string. but when I want to use it in react native, tell me `Invalid predicate`.
i tried to use @"%name IN $NAME_LIST".

Comment: The react native query syntax doesn't conform 100% to NSPredicate. You use numbered arguments `$0`, ... -- take a look at the [.filtered() docs](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/1.0.0/api/Realm.Collection.html#filtered)